# Uploading .pdf files to MySQL in batch mode with PHP not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have code to allow user to select one PDF file and upload it to MySQL, and it works perfectly.

```
// Gather all required data
        $name = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_FILES['ogx_pdf']['name']);
        $mime = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_FILES['ogx_pdf']['type']);
        $data = $dbcon->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['ogx_pdf']['tmp_name']));
        $size = $dbcon->strval($_FILES['ogx_pdf']['size']);
        $unid = $_POST['unid'] ;
        $comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'] ;
        // Create the SQL query
        $call = "
            INSERT INTO `deal_attachment` (
                `att_name`, `att_mime`, `att_size`, `att_content`, `att_created` , `att_unid` , `att_comment_id`
            )
            VALUES (
                '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$_FILES['ogx_pdf']['size']}, '{$data}', NOW(), '{$unid}' , '{$comment_id}'
            )";

        // Execute the query

        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$call) ;
```

But this needs input from $_FILES (all examples I have researched here and other websites go the same route).

Now I need to extend this to upload many PDF files and store them appropriately.  The code reads a list of files sequentially, locates the file and uploads it OK, but when I try to read the attachment from the database,  PDF app fails - something is wrong in the content.

```
$file = fopen($path ."ogx_attach.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
    $line =fgetcsv($file);
    // Gather all required data
    $name = $dbcon->real_escape_string($path .  $line[0]);
    $data = $dbcon->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($name));
    $size =  (string)(strlen($data));
    $filename = trim($name) ;
    $dateymd =  date("Y/m/d") ;
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO `deal_attachment` (
            `att_name`, `att_mime`, `att_size`,  `att_created`, `att_content`
        )
        VALUES ('{$name}', 'application/pdf', {$size},  '{$dateymd}', '" . $data . "')";


    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query) ;

    // Check if it was successfull
    if (false === $result) {
        echo mysqli_error($dbcon);
        die ;
    } else
    { 
        //echo 'Success! Your row was successfully added!';
```

The blob in the row does contain something, but PDF objects when trying to open.  I think there is something different between the two processes.  $_FILES  ['ogx_pdf']['tmp_name'] is pointing to a temporary file in folder binaries/tmp where it has been stored in some different format. It looks like file_get_contents($name) is not equivalent to file_get_contents($_FILES  ['ogx_pdf']['tmp_name']).

Any help appreciated.